# How To Return Null From The Method Where We Return Data Table C# Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to return the null or some null table from the method where i return data table in case of some error  my code is given below,

```
  public DataTable CostOfKilowat()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable CostDT = new DataTable();
                int Dollar = Convert.ToInt32(txtCommission.Text);
                CostDT = GetProducts();
                DataTable Costtable = GetCostRate(CostDT, Dollar, "DATE,MTU,POWER,COST,VOLTAGE,PERUNITCOST", "DATE", "Group by ");
                return Costtable;
            }
            catch 
            {
                String script = "<script>alert('Enter Valid Cost')</script>";
                Page.RegisterStartupScript("script", script);
            }
            return ;
        }
```

hopes for your suggestions...

Comment: I'm sorry if I've misread, but `return null;`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you rephrase it please?

Comment: @all i added mu post and i return data table in this method in case of any error how do i return null ? and want to give error nessage also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your function definition, I'm assuming you want to return a table so that you can bind that information to a grid or something?

Are you asking how to return an empty grid, or did you really want to know how to return null?

For the empty grid, with all the column names brought back, you would just need to make sure the stored procedure (or whatever server call you make), still `selects` all the fields even when the `where` clause makes it return nothing.

Then you have to change your code to always return the table:

```
public DataTable CostOfKilowat()
{
    DataTable CostDT = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        int Dollar = Convert.ToInt32(txtCommission.Text);
        CostDT = GetProducts();
        DataTable Costtable = GetCostRate(CostDT, Dollar, "DATE,MTU,POWER,COST,VOLTAGE,PERUNITCOST", "DATE", "Group by ");
        return Costtable;
    }
    catch 
    {
        String script = "<script>alert('Enter Valid Cost')</script>";
        Page.RegisterStartupScript("script", script);
    }
    return CostDT;
}
```

If you really want to return null... um.. `return null;`

Answer (score 3):

Change the last line to:

```
return null;
```

Comment: Capitan obvious ! ( typo fixed >_< )

Comment: @nCdy: No probs. I'm a little hungover today so I was afraid I'd missed something _really_ obvious!

Answer (score 0):

added another easy answer according to answer in the comments of question :

```
  public DataTable CostOfKilowat()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable CostDT = new DataTable();
                int Dollar = Convert.ToInt32(txtCommission.Text);
                CostDT = GetProducts();
                DataTable Costtable = GetCostRate(CostDT, Dollar, "DATE,MTU,POWER,COST,VOLTAGE,PERUNITCOST", "DATE", "Group by ");
                return Costtable;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                String script = "<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>";
                Page.RegisterStartupScript("script", script);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Not sure if I get it, but maybe that's what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Hi his is how I'd write it:

```
public DataTable CostOfKilowat()
    {
        DataTable Costtable = null;
        try
        {
            int Dollar = Convert.ToInt32(txtCommission.Text);
            DataTable CostDT = GetProducts();
            Costtable = GetCostRate(CostDT, Dollar, "DATE,MTU,POWER,COST,VOLTAGE,PERUNITCOST", "DATE", "Group by ");
        }
        catch 
        {
            String script = "<script>alert('Enter Valid Cost')</script>";
            Page.RegisterStartupScript("script", script);
        }
        return Costtable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

return new DataTable();

Comment: Hi @RyanU, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I think your answer does solve OP's problem, but it could be improved in a couple ways. First: code should always be formatted as such, which can be done by indenting it four spaces, or wrapping it in `\`` characters. Second: it's helpful to explain *why* your solution works. In this case, a `new DataTable()` is an empty table. And third: a combination of the two, you can help OP even more by inserting your code into theirs, in the right place and clearly marked as such, so that they know exactly what to do with the help you've given :)